# Set fixed page height when using MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm kind of new to MVC, and I have an issue defining fixed page height.

I will first say that I use MVC3. I have several pages, and a login page. All should have fixed height. It doesn't have to be size in pixels, it also can be in percents, but it shouldn't be affected by the content of the page.

Currently I added the "he

```
body {
background-color: White;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: Black;
height: 100%;
}
```

and:

```
.page {
width: 90%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
color: White;  
height: 100%; 
}
```

I also tried "1000px" instead of "100%", it also didn't work...
my pages' height is still defined automatically according to page's content....

EDIT:
My page code:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both the html and the body element to 100%, ie

body,html{height:100%;}

Then I guess you'll also have to cope with overflow on the elements you want to be of fixed height, so something like

.page
{overflow:hidden;}

Comment: You're going to have to post some more details then. It could be something like malformed HTML. Try putting it on jsFiddle.

Comment: Where is the element with the class 'page'? Make things easy for an old man, I beg you.

Comment: it's MVC... this page is rendered under the _Layout, it's basically something like that:
<div class="page">
      <section id="main">
            @RenderBody() --> Here is my printscreened page
        </section>
</div>

Comment: can you set this up on the internet somewhere? Or post the entire markup you get when you view page source, plus your stylesheet. Alternatively, if you're feeling frisky, open it up in Internet Explorer and press F12 to get the developer tools. Then select the 'page' class div and examine its properties to see why it's not getting what you think it should be getting. Or do the equivalent thing in Firefox, or your browser of choice.